# Function that calls itself doesn't return true

Tags: javascript

I call a function "returnsTrue" which calls itself when parameter "redo" is set to true. Then I recall the same function "returnsTrue" with parameter "redo" set to false and I want to return true. But in fact I only get "undefined" back.

I can't really understand what is going on here:

```
function returnsTrue(redo){
    if(redo){
    console.log('Restart Function');
    returnsTrue(false);
  }else{
    console.log('It returns true');
    return true;
  }
}

if(returnsTrue(true)){
    console.log('1');
}else{
    console.log('2');
}

var isTrue = returnsTrue(true);
console.log(isTrue);
// is undefined
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/8820r2ug/

Comment: @Armin it's a synchronous method - no waiting is required.

Answer (score 6):

There are two branches to the `if` statement.

Only **one** of those two branches includes a `return` statement.

If it hits the `if` (and not the `else`) then there is no `return` statement and it returns `undefined`.

You need to add a `return` statement to the `if` side of the `if`/`else`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Line 4 in code block should be: 
return returnsTrue(false);

Comment: In other words use `return returnsTrue(false);` instead of `returnsTrue(false);` in if statement

Answer (score 3):

So what's happening is the assignment call isn't returning a value, it's the call within the function that's returning true, so your assignment ends up undefined, try returning the function call within the function like so:

```
function returnsTrue(redo){
    if(redo){
    console.log('Restart Function');
    return returnsTrue(false);
  }else{
    console.log('It returns true');
    return true;
  }
}

if(returnsTrue(true)){
    console.log('1');
}else{
    console.log('2');
}

var isTrue = returnsTrue(true);
console.log(isTrue);
// is undefined
```